# How do I access a String in a Custom Object that I embedded in an Array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

(First time posting to the forum!)

I was able to successfully create an NSMutableArray that has a custom object at each index, but I can not access the data in my object when I reference that Object again elsewhere in my code.

This is what my NSMutableArray looks like when I output it to NSLog:

```
items = (
"<RSSFeedList: 0x682cbb0>",
"<RSSFeedList: 0x682f570>",
"<RSSFeedList: 0x68300a0>"
```

)

As you can see, at each index I have my custom object.  Now, I was able to get to a specific Object by using the following code:

```
[items objectAtIndex:1]
```

Which outputs to NSLog:

```
<RSSFeedList: 0x602f250>
```

However, I would like to access the information in that object and right now I'm stuck.. That Objects structure looks like this:

```
@interface RSSFeedList : NSObject {

NSString *subject;
NSMutableArray *rssfeedDetail;
```

}

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RSSFeedLists *rssfeedDetail;
```

I would simply like to reference the NSString "Subject".

This is what I have tried:

```
RSSFeedList *fl = [[RSSFeedList alloc] init];

fl = [items objectAtIndex:1];

NSString *subject = (NSString *) [fl getSubjectText];
```

**I would like to note that this block of code is in another class that received the NSMutableArray "item" from another class, so that is why I am re-instantiating the RSSFeedListObject (Not sure if this part is right)**

Also, getSubjectText is defined in the RSSFeedList Class and looks like this:

```
-(NSString *) getSubjectText{
return subject ;
```

}

When I try all of that I get a (null) value when I output it to NSLog... Any ideas???

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: If you want to get the value 0x602f250 then you have to parse it. NSMutableArray doesnt work like a hash table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your result, it would appear to be a problem with how you are setting the subject value on your RSSFeedList objects.  My guess is that a value is not correctly being stored in the subject value.  Take a look at the following code which shows the an example of the  set/retrieval of the RSSFeelList values:

RSSFeelList.h

```
see your code
```

RSSFeedList.m

```
@implementation RSSFeedList

@synthesize subject, rssfeedDetail;

// generates a usable log text
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RSSFeedList {subject=%@}", self.subject];
}

@end
```

other *.m

```
// populate list
NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
RSSFeedList *f = [[RSSFeedList alloc] init];
f.subject = @"test subject";
[list addObject:f];
[f release];

// access data
NSLog(@"Value = %@", list);
RSSFeedList *f2 = [list objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *s = f2.subject;
NSLog(@"Value = %@", s);
// ...
```

You do not need to release the value retrieved from the array unless you copy or retain it.  Otherwise the value is managed by the Array itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was definitely the way i was setting the object.... I was adding the object RSSFeedList to the items array properly, but I wasn't setting the actual RSSFeedList objects correctly. I followed your example and it worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: How would I add an array to my object?  For the string 'subject' you just did f.subject = @"test subject"; ... For my NSMutableArray *rssfeedDetail; I'm trying things like "[f.rssfeedDetail addObject:rssItems];" .. where rssItems is another object that I'm embedding to no avail.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you initialized the rssfeedDetail Array?  You need to do this either in an init override method in RSSFeedList.m or set it to a value when you instantiate the RSSFeedList, e.g., f.rssfeedDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init autorelease].

Comment: In the other *.m file I added this line after the RSSFeedList declaration and it's throwing an exception:    RSSFeedList *f = [[RSSFeedList alloc] init];   f.rssfeedDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; .. not sure why.. thanks again for your help!

Comment: And the error is: -[RSSFeedList setRssfeedDetail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x682f280
2011-02-23 18:29:19.774 TestApp[37344:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RSSFeedList setRssfeedDetail:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x682f280'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just doing this:

```
RSSFeedList *fl = [items objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *subject = [fl getSubjectText];
```

This *should* work. There are a few things that you should improve with your code (such as using `@property`s with `Subject` [which should be lowercase, by the way] and making sure you're not leaking memory [which your `init`+assignment did]) but this should be a start.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did use the @property tag in the object.  Added the edit above and thanks for the naming suggestion!  I just tried what you suggested though and it's still showing up null...